# Insert sysdate with a fixed timestamp into table column

Tags: sql, oracle

Any suggestions on how to insert sysdate value with a fixed timestamp into column. below is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO
    TABLE1 (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6, COLUMN7)

VALUES      
('VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4', SYSDATE, 
TO_TIMESTAMP('SYSDATE 19:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS'),SYSDATE);
```

The goal is to get the current sysdate and insert it into the database with a fixed timestamp. the value: `TO_TIMESTAMP('SYSDATE 19:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS')` returns the following oracle errors:

> sql  Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between
>   -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>   *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>   *Action:   Input year in the specified range

Suggestions will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Use a PreparedStatement and then `setDate`

Comment: @ScaryWombat im new in sql. can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you new to google as well?  Here is a result from a quick search https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `TRUNC` function with `TO_DSINTERVAL` or `INTERVAL` hours to use a fixed timestamp.

```
CAST ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) + TO_DSINTERVAL('00 '||'19:00:00') as timestamp)
```

OR

```
CAST ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '19' HOUR as timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')  || ' 19:00:00', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```